# Google sheets Script - Sort sheet by column AP under category headers (colored background)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am fairly new to Javascript/Apps Script.

I have a sheet that contains a few categories and their data on a single sheet. I am trying to create a script that sorts whats under each category (header) by column AP.

Currently we are manually selecting the range then running the following macro to sort by the column.

```
function SortAP() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange()
  .sort({column: 42, ascending: true});
};
```

I want to have this query a row for a header and then run the function. Is this possible?

[Here is an example sheet of what our headers look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGXTE.png)

Answer (score 0):

#### Sort Each Column

```
function sortEachColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//Edit sheet name as necessary
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  [...Array.from(new Array(sh.getLastColumn()).keys(),x => sh.getRange(2,x+1,sh.getLastRow()).sort({column:x + 1,ascending:true}))];
}
```

[image]

[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)